# Calculate a sucess rate depending on a percentage set by a value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am deeply sorry if this question has been asked and answered already but I couldn't find anything related online. To be honest I'm not even sure what should I search for haha.

So, I want to calculate if a result is a success(true) or a fail(false) depending on a predetermined fixed percentage and a value.

To explain my example:
I want to calculate the success of a **mission** based on the **number** of **operative** doing it.

- Using 1 operative, mission success rate of 50%. (50%to be a success /
  50% to be a fail)
- Using 2 operatives, mission success rate of 60%. (60%to be a success /
  40% to be a fail)
- Using 3 operatives, mission success rate of 70%. (70%to be a success /
  30% to be a fail)

Is this possible to somehow translate that into google sheet formula?

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A=1, 0.5, 
              IF(A2:A=2, 0.6, 
              IF(A2:A=3, 0.7, ))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

=IFS(K2="sh1",IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,100)>40,"YES","NO"),K2="sh2",IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,100)>20,"YES","NO"),K2="sh3",IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,100)>10,"YES","NO"))